# Total power periodic voltage develops in a resistor

Tags: power, harmonics

[image]

What's the total power this voltage develops in a resistor of 2 ohms?

What I got: total power is $$S=UI$$ where U and I are both effective and calculated as a square root of a sum of squares of effective values.

Is effective value for a zero harmonic 2 or a square root of 2?

Similar question, what happens when this voltage is superimposed with u1(t)=2V? Is the amplitude of every harmonic increased, or only the one of the zero harmonic?

Any mistakes? 
13/4 is what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seperate all the harmonics into individual sinewaves. Calculate power in the resistor (i.e. V^2/R) for each. Add all the powers up. Job done.

Alternatively take all the individual RMS voltages from each sinewave and add them up like this Total RMS = \$\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2 + etc}\$.

Then divide that by 2 ohms and you get the same value as I first mentioned.

If you add 2V DC to the signal still treat like an example of superimposition - it does not affect any harmonics or the power dissipated by the harmonics.

> Is effective value for a zero harmonic 2 or a square root of 2?

It's 2V not sqrt(2)

Comment: are you sure total power isn't $$S^2=P^2+Q^2+D^2$$, where D isn't zero since there are multiple harmonics?

Comment: that's a power formula and if you take the square root you get the rms voltageas stated in my answer.